# Get all combinations of a type

Tags: typescript

```
type base = { a: number; b: string }

type all_combinations<T> = .... // *missing*

type result = all_combinations<base>

// result = {} | {a:number} | {b:string} |  { a: number; b: string }
```

Can I achieve that? How?

---

- I'm not looking for a solution like this: `{ a?: number; b?: string }`. ***It's not the same type as what I'm searching for***.

If it's not that hard, I would like to only get a clue ;)

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but does `{ a?: number; b?: string }` do what you need?

Comment: no. it's not what I'm searching for.

Comment: It might be possible, a good source of inspiration could be the [utility-types](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types) project

Comment: @ProdigySim Thats a nice project. Thanks! Also, can you be more specific on what I may need from there?

Comment: `Unionize<T>` would give you `{a:number}` and `{b: string}` from `base`. Which would be enough to solve this for cases where `num_properties = 2`. But you would need more to find all permutations of types.

Comment: 100% possible, i'll post a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to solve any problem one way is to do this...

```
type Base = { a: number; b: string; c: number }

type Combinations<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Combinations<Omit<T, K>> | Pick<T, K>
}[keyof T]

type TestCombinations = Combinations<Base> | Base | {}
// should be what you want give it a whirl and let me know.
```

Another way is to do this which is more manual per-key

```
export type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;
export type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };

type AWithoutBBWithoutA = XOR<Omit<Base, "a">, Omit<Base, "b">>;

type Base = { a: number; b: string;}
const test: AWithoutBBWithoutA ={
    a: 5
} // fine

const test1: AWithoutBBWithoutA ={
    b: "fine"
} // fine


const test2: AWithoutBBWithoutA  = {
    a: 5,
    b: "asd"
} // error
```

Let me know if that's along the lines of what you were looking for.

EDIT: I think the top one is definitely a preferred solution; Also as an edit i would like to add that OP doesn't need a permutations algorithm to solve this; {a: number, b: string} ==== {b: string, a: number} Object key ordering is irrelevant;

Comment: This is an amazing solution. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think this generates a type with each property individually. It create {a,b}, {b,c}, {a,c} but not {a}, {b}, {c}. Given N properties, I think this will create all combinations of length N-1.

Comment: I don't think you'll want empty object in there as that will allow the object type to expand out to allow {g: "ANYTHING"} will now be allowed but added anyway

Comment: Maybe make it recursive? `[K in keyof T]: Combinations<Omit<T, K>> | Pick<T,K>`

Comment: Good idea i'll update it now forgot he wanted individual keys aswell

Comment: @ShanonJackson The first solutin doesn't work with recursive types, such as: `type employee = Combinations<{manager:employee}>
const employee1:employee = {manager:1} // it complies!! but should be an error!` when Combinations is defined as `type Combinations<T> =
  | {
      [K in keyof T]: Combinations<Omit<T, K>> | Pick<T, K>
    }[keyof T]
  | T
  | {}
`. Is there any way to fix that? If not, it's still probably the best I will get. almost :P

Comment: In the first solution, `TestCombinations` should use `Record<string,never>` instead of `{}`. `{}` allows any property of any type. E.g. `{ a: boolean }` would be legal when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are looking for:

```
type all_combinations<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P]; };
```

Usually this is called `Partial`

Comment: There are some differences between this type and the type OP is asking for. For example, trying to access the type of a property: `ResultType['b']`

Comment: sory, this is not what i want searching for. please read the end of my question.